# Сделать положительное число

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Потребовалось перевести из отрицательной переменной в положительную. Как это сделать в python?

Comment: Умножить на -1?

Comment: `a = -2; a = -a; print(a)`

Comment: Взять по модулю -  `abs(a)`

Comment: В заголовке одно, в вопросе совсем противоположное.

Comment: @Эникейщик исправил!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Вступление

Допустим,

```
a = 5
b = -2
```

Дальнейшие примеры будут выглядеть таким образом:

```
print(пример)  # вывод
```

---

## Как перевернуть знак?

В python, чтобы поменять знак какого-либо числа в переменной `num`, надо записать `-num`:

```
print(-a)  # -5
print(-b)  # 2
```

---

## Как сделать положительное число?

### Быстрый способ

Чтобы перевести любое число в ранг положительных, нужно написать `abs(num)`:

```
print(abs(a))  # 5
print(abs(b))  # 2
```

Почему этот способ самый быстрый?

> Этот способ самый быстрый, т.к. здесь используется встроенная функция, написанная на быстром Си, и она будет быстрее любого другого способа с использованием других встроенных функций.

---

### Математический способ

Это более медленный и длинный в написании способ. Для этой задачи не рекомендую его использовать.
Записать можно по-разному, но я приведу два различных способа:

```
print((a**2)**0.5)  # 5
print((b**2)**0.5)  # 2
```

и

```
from math import pow, sqrt

print(sqrt(pow(a, 2)))  # 5
print(sqrt(pow(b, 2)))  # 2
```

Как это работает?

> Чтобы получить модуль числа (то же число, только всегда положительное) число надо возвести в квадрат и извлечь квадратный корень.
> В питоне можно по-разному записать эти операции, один способ - `**` (возведение в степень), другой - воспользоваться встроенной библиотекой `math`.
> Возведение в 2 степень - возведение в квадрат, а в 0.5 - эквивалентно извлечению квадратного корня.
> Также для возведения в степень можно использовать функцию `math.pow`, а для извлечения квадратного корня - `math.sqrt`.

---

## Вывод

Наш выбор для создания положительного числа - использовать функцию `abs`!
Соединяя инверсию знака с созданием положительного числа мы получаем следующее:

> Чтобы перевести любое число `num` в ранг отрицательных, надо записать `-abs(num)`

Пример:

```
print(-abs(a))  # -5
print(-abs(b))  # -2
```

---

## Ремарки

- Для простоты понимания я опустил деталь, что при использования математического
  способа результат - `float`, а не `int`, и при выводе `.0` добавляется к числу.
- Изначально в вопросе просилось сделать отрицательное число.

Comment: чем абс быстрее степени ? там ведь одинаковые действия происходят

Comment: @Интик, потому, что встроенные функции python уже скомпилированы и отлажены, также написаны на более низкоуровневом языке.
Любой код, который написан вами будет работать медленнее, чем встроенные функции.

```from timeit import timeit

a = 5
b = -2

for str_ in ["abs(a)", "abs(b)", "(a**2)**0.5", "(b**2)**0.5"]:
    print(timeit(str_, number=100000, globals=globals()))
```

вывод:
0.016207299999999925
0.016764
0.05224659999999992
0.0510275
первые 2 - abs,
вторые два - **2)**0.5
вот сравнивайте
встроенная функция примерно в три раза быстрее

Comment: как вы такой спойлер делаете?

Comment: @PeterKolosov `>!Текст`

Comment: @0dminnimda Спасибо!